# Error: Unable to find file with path: prelude_dev.js

Tags: android, react-native

I'm getting the following error when I run the packager:

```
Error: Unable to find file with path: /Users/erem/thrivespace/react-mobile/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/prelude_dev.js
    at Fastfs.readFile (/Users/erem/thrivespace/react-mobile/node_modules/node-haste/lib/fastfs.js:141:15)
    at /Users/erem/thrivespace/react-mobile/node_modules/node-haste/lib/Module.js:168:49
    at Cache.get (/Users/erem/thrivespace/react-mobile/node_modules/node-haste/lib/Cache/index.js:64:103)
    at Polyfill.read (/Users/erem/thrivespace/react-mobile/node_modules/node-haste/lib/Module.js:167:26)
    at Bundler._toModuleTransport (index.js:524:14)
    at toModuleTransport (index.js:400:14)
    at Array.map (native)
    at index.js:416:48
    at tryCallOne (/Users/erem/thrivespace/react-mobile/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/erem/thrivespace/react-mobile/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
```

I've already ran:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

I'm currently running React Native 0.24.0.

Answer (score 2):

It's a cache issue.  See: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1924

You need to clear your packager cache:

`rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*`

Or this appears to do the trick also:

`watchman watch-del-all`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using your own rn-cli.config.js try without it.

I've wasted many hours with this with a bad rn-cli.config.js file. It worked for a while until it didn't.

---

In my case I was using this:

```
var blacklist = require('react-native/packager/blacklist');
var config = {
    getBlacklistRE(platform) {
        return blacklist(platform, [
            /src/
        ]);
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

when I should have used this instead:

```
var blacklist = require('react-native/packager/blacklist');
var config = require('react-native/packager/rn-cli.config');
config.getBlacklistRE = function(platform) {
    return blacklist(platform, [
        /src/
    ]);
};
module.exports = config;
```